# Animating custom UIButton in UITableViewCell

Tags: iphone, ios, cocoa-touch, uitableview, uibutton

I'm having trouble getting an animation to display when a `UIButton` is tapped in a custom UITableViewCell.  The `IBAction` is being called correctly.  I want a blue shadow to appear around the `UIButton`.  Here's the code:

```
-(IBAction)handleButtonTap:(UIButton*)sender {
[self animateBlueShadowAroundView:sender];
}

-(void)animateBlueShadowAroundView:(UIView*)view {
[UIView animateWithDuration:1.0 animations:^{ [self configureBlueShadow:view]; } ];
}

-(void)configureBlueShadow:(UIView*)view {
view.layer.shadowColor = [UIColor blueColor].CGColor;
view.layer.shadowRadius = 7.0;
view.layer.shadowOpacity = 1.0;
}
```

I also tried doing the animation in `cellForRowAtIndexPath` and reloading the row that needed the animation, but that didn't work either.  I would prefer for the animation to happen as part of the above `IBAction` `handleButtonTap:`.

Nothing happens.  I don't see any animation at all, but I am confirming the above `IBAction` is being called.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Oops.  I should have read more about CALayers and Core Animation.

`UIView`'s animation methods (as I used above) can only animate certain properties.  To animate properties of the `CALayer` you must use Core Animation classes and methods, not `UIView`'s.

Here's a great reference I found:
[apeth.com/iOSBook](http://www.apeth.com/iOSBook/ch17.html)

From the reference:

> Animation is ultimately layer animation. However, for a limited range
>   of attributes, you can animate a UIView directly: these are its
>   alpha,backgroundColor, bounds, center, frame, and transform.